# Using Chinese Characters to Name MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql

What precautions must be taken to use Chinese characters as MySQL table names?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: May I ask why would one want to do it? Table names are for programmer eyes only.

Comment: IIRC, MySQL server 5.0+ should be able to handle that ("The allowable Unicode characters are those in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)." -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html ). Not so sure about client-side support, though - I'm pretty sure at least one assumes ASCII identifiers.p

Comment: I expect a Chinese programmer might wish to do so. Yes it's true that programming is generally done in a sort of pseudo-English but that shouldn't have to be the case.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM 音信 WHERE 称号 = '鸭'` .. how's that >_____<

Answer (score 2):

SQL supports **delimited identifiers** to allow table or column names to contain SQL keywords, whitespace, punctuation, other special characters, or international characters.

In MySQL, use back-quotes (or set the `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode to use standard double-quotes).

Example:

```
mysql> create table `桌子` (id serial);
mysql> show create table `桌子`\G
--------------
show create table `桌子`
--------------

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: 桌子
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `桌子` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be sure to properly escape table name anywhere using backqoutes. Besides this, it should be pretty safe to use any characters.

PS: And whenever non Chinese writing person will have to modify your code he will hate you for that.

Comment: I'm a white American who speaks zero Chinese, yet I can't imagine why I'd have a problem with it.  It's not like it'd be the first time I saw a cryptic and unpronounceable table name.  Except if it's in Chinese I can actually google it, so that'd be a marked improvement over most projects I've worked on.

Comment: The problem is that you can not type it and you need to copy and paste the name all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can probably do it safely within MySQL, whether it's right or wrong the reality is that you may end up having a hard time finding support for table names with unicode characters when using third party tools. That might include back-up solutions, development languages and APIs, etc. While it's nice to try to be global thinking, in this case I would probably stick with "standard" table names.