# Chinese Characters as mySQL Table name in PHP

Tags: php

How do I use Chinese characters as Table name in mySQL using PHP. Currently it does not returns any error but creates a table with name "???".

Any idea what needs to be done? Or it cannot be done?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1908976/1084754) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set MySQL charset to UTF-8 or GBK or GB2312 like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (c CHAR(20) CHARACTER SET gbk COLLATE gbk_chinse_ci);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every SQL statement uses identifiers in some way to refer to a database or its constituent
elements such as tables, views, columns, indexes, stored routines, triggers, or events. When
you refer to elements of databases, identifiers must conform to the following rules.

Legal characters in identifiers. Unquoted identifiers may consist of latin letters `a-z` in any
lettercase, digits `0-9` , `dollar`, `underscore`, and `Unicode extended` characters in the range `U+0080
to U+FFFF`.

Identifiers can start with any character that is legal in an identifier, including a
digit. However, an unquoted identifier **cannot consist entirely of digits** because that would
make it indistinguishable from a number. MySQL’s support for identifiers that begin with
a number is somewhat unusual among database systems. If you use such an identifier, take
particular care if it contains an ‘ E ’ or ‘ e ’ because those characters **can lead** to ambiguous expressions.

For example, the expression `23e + 14` (with spaces surrounding the ‘ + ’ sign) means
column `23e` plus the number `14` , but what about `23e+14` ? Does it mean the same thing, or is it
a number in scientific notation?

Identifiers can be quoted (delimited) within `backtick` characters (' `'), which permits use of **any
character**, except a`NUL`byte or`Unicode supplementary`characters (`U+10000 and up`). Your operating system might impose additional constraints on database and table identifiers.